# what does "<cmake_binary_dir>/bin" mean?

Tags: cmake

I want to populate with some script files in  the /bin subdirectory of  CMake directory, but can not find the /bin file.
What can I give guys some advice?

Thanks

Comment: See [CMAKE_BINARY_DIR — CMake Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BINARY_DIR.html).

Answer (score 23):

I have to disagree with gvd's answer, since `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` should always point to the top level directory of the build tree. If you need the location of the build tree where the current `CMakelists.txt` goes to, use `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`

> CMAKE_BINARY_DIR
>
> if you are building in-source, this is the same as CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR,
> otherwise this is the top level directory of your build tree
>
> CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR
>
> if you are building in-source, this is the same as CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR,
> otherwise this  is the directory where the compiled or generated files from the
> current CMakeLists.txt will go to

So the answer is: cmake_binary_dir/bin points to toplevelBuilddir/bin

Answer (score 5):

CMAKE_BINARY_DIR is the build folder location of your CMakeLists.txt file.

Say you have:

`MyProject/application/CMakeLists.txt`
and your build output is in `MyProject/build`

when using CMAKE_BINARY_DIR in the above CMakeLists.txt, it points to `MyProject/build/application/`

Have a look at [this](http://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables) list of CMake variables for more variables.

Comment: Thanks, your advice is very important to me. 
But I can not find the "/bin" file, or "/bin" what does that mean?

Comment: Do you understand how cmake works? First of all, is there a bin folder in your source tree? If there is a "bin" folder and it contains a CMakeLists.txt that is being processed, CMake will create that folder also in the build folder. It mirrors the source folder.

Comment: Oh,got it. I just started learning Cmake as the project needs.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just to say that cmake sets CMAKE_BINARY_DIR to your pwd when you first run it. So, if your src is all in /MyProject/application and you have /MyProject/application/CMakeFiles.txt, then if you cd /MyProject/build/application and type cmake /MyProject/application, you will find that CMAKE_BINARY_DIR=/MyProject/build/application